# Best way to prevent physics calculations in Unity from eating too much FPS?

Tags: unity-game-engine, steamvr

I'm a senior software engineer, but completely new to Unity programming. I've been teaching myself Unity for a few weeks by writing some SteamVR toys for myself. I wanted to ask about Unity's standard built-in ways to improve frame rate for a program with a lot of intensive physics calculation.

In my current VR scene, I have a ball with a `Rigidbody` on it. When I pick it up and throw it, I let it move naturally, but I apply small forces on every `Update()` call to adjust the landing position and always hit a target.

I saw my framerate take a big dive, so I wrote my own function to throttle the updates, limiting them to 5 per second. The question is, is there some standard Unity behavior that I should be using instead of rolling this code myself?

In my throwing script, I maintain a bunch of top level variables and update them first to decide whether I should do calculations on the current frame.

```
private void updateCalculationFrame() {
    isCalculationFrame = Time.time > nextCalculationTime;
    while (nextCalculationTime < Time.time) {
        nextCalculationTime += (1 / calculationsPerSecond);
    }
}
```

On each frame, I run this function, then if `isCalculationFrame` is true, I proceed to calculate and add force vectors. I just wonder if I am overlooking some more standard way to do this with less code? I feel like this must be a very common thing to try to do.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have there will freeze the Unity until the loop is finished. You shouldn't do this at all.

You could simply set a new [`Time.fixedDeltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-fixedDeltaTime.html). By default it is usually about `0.02` but you can set it to anything you want.

> The interval in seconds at which physics and other fixed frame rate updates (like MonoBehaviour's `FixedUpdate`) are performed.
>
> ...
>
> Note that the `fixedDeltaTime` interval is with respect to the in-game time affected by timeScale.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The loop doesn't freeze Unity because the heavy calculation doesn't occur inside the loop; it's only updating the anticipated time when the next calculation should occur. It's only looping to guarantee that the next update will happen in the future; usually it runs once, and rarely it could run two or three times. I'll look into fixedDeltaTime, but I'm wondering if it affects every FixedUpdate when I only want it to apply to this particular function.